# SQL Server seed value lower than max identity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity

I have a table that contains a a column, integer, that is specified as an auto-incrementing primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [TableKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [...]
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [TableKey] ASC
    ) 
    WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
        FILLFACTOR = 80
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table has been having anywhere from 0 - 7000 records inserted into M-F, without issue. Last Friday ~4K records were inserted with identity values starting at 2,064,682 and ending at 2,068,076. Then this morning I received an error...

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TableKey'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table'. The duplicate key value is
>   (2067844).

After going down a lot of wrong paths I found that the current seed was Table `2067845`.

My question is, because I cannot find anything related, is how could this happen? I see, and understand, why you may see a higher seed than max identity, but not the other way around.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be someone has run a `RESEED` command.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 Identity column has been problematic ever since the release of 2012, Skipping identity values, not following the seed correctly etc...

You can log a bug with microsoft at [`Microsoft Connect`](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Here are some of the other knows bugs logged on connect about Identity column

[`Identity Column jumps by Seed value`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value)

[`Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)

Also to fix this you can execute the following commands

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0) --<-- to any smallest value 0 would do the trick
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED)    --<-- Without any seed value
```

This will reseed the identity column to next available highest identity value. saving you from future duplicate issues.

Comment: Both of your "bugs" are the same thing and aren't bugs. Closed as "by design". Gaps aren't a bug. Duplicate values would be.